# discord.py play command has problems with opus while using heroku

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a play command in my bot

```
@client.command()
    async def play(ctx, url):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice.is_playing():
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice.is_playing()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Already playing song")
        return
```

and a `discord.opus.load_opus("opus")` line at the start. When I try to run the command I get this error `OSError: opus: cannot read file data: Is a directory`

**PS** I'm using Heroku to run the bot 24/7

Comment: Install an opus buildpack.

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to mention that I already installed this [buildpack](https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git)

Comment: Try running it without the load_opus line, I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I couldn't think that the solution was this easy :D

Comment: BTW I wrote that repository you linked ;) A star would be appreciated.

Comment: You have my star then mate :D

Comment: Btw can I ask you a few questions about heroku and discord.py (I need to make a queue :D)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226612/discussion-between-fat-bulbasaur-and-xrisk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `discord.opus.load_opus("opus")` isn't required; you can safely remove it.

The https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git buildpack already adds opus to the library path. No further configuration is needed :)

Comment: Umm do you have a discord or something so that it would be easier to help me if you want to.